# Lambda execution time out after 15 mins what I can do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a script running on Lambda, I've set the timeout to maximum 15 mins but it's still giving me time out error, there is not much infomation in the lofs, how I can solve this issue and spot what is taking soo much time? I tested the script locally and it's fairly quick.

Here's the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2020-09-10T18:26:53.180Z xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 900.10 seconds"
}
```

Comment: You will need to add some logging to the Lambda function to pinpoint where it is hanging.

Comment: @MarkB how can I do this? Could you please provide more details pleas? Lambda is trying to connect to a sql db and query some data then upload to a bucket.

Comment: There is likely to be one step that is 'hanging', or at least taking a long time to complete. The easiest way to debug this situation is to insert `print()` statements to track what the Lambda function is doing. The information will be displayed in CloudWatch Logs, so you can check how far the function got before it timed-out, to locate what is causing it to hang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're exceeding the 15 minutes period there are a few things you should check to identify:

- Is the Lambda connecting to resources in a VPC? If so is it attached via VPC config, and do the target resources allow inbound access from the Lambda.
- Is the Lambda connecting to a public IP but using VPC configuration? If so it will need a NAT attached to allow outbound access.
- Are there any long running processes as part of your Lambda?

Once you've ruled these out consider increasing the available resources of your Lambda, perhaps its hitting a cap and is therefore performing slow. Increasing the memory will also increase the available CPU for you.

Adding comments in the code will log to CloudWatch logs, these can help you identify where in the code the slowness starts. This is done by simply calling the general output/debug function of your language i.e. `print()` in Python or `console.log()` in NodeJS.

If the function is still expected to last longer than 15 minutes after this you will need to break it down into smaller functions performing logical segments of the operation

A suggested orchestrator for this would be to use a [step function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to handle the workflow for each stage. If you need shared storage between each Lambda you can make use of [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) to be attached to all of your Lambdas so that they do not need to upload/download between the operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment about it connecting to a SQL DB is likely the key.  I assume that DB is in AWS in your VPC.  This requires particular setup.  Check out

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html

Another thing you can do is enable debug level logging and then look at the details in CloudWatch after trying to run it.  You didn't mention which language your lambda uses, so how to do this could be different for the language you use.  Here's how it would be done in python:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.getLevelName('DEBUG'))
```